# How to change the background color of the TabPanel in a TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, tabpanel

I know how to set the background color of a TabPanel in xaml like this:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="noClue" TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

However, I want to change this background color when I click a button on the WPF application, which means changing it at run-time. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bind the TabPanel's Background property to a property in your View/ViewModel and change it when you click the button. The XAML for the binding would look something like so using:

```
<TabPanel Background="{Binding Path=BackgroundColor}"/>
```

Where your property name is BackgroundColor. The Background is a [Brush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brush(v=vs.110).aspx) so take that into account when you manage your bindings. You can also achieve the binding from the style, but you may need a [RelativeSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599(v=vs.110).aspx)

In a style, try this

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}" />
```

If your window is bound to a DataContext. Also try removing x:Key from your style. It is not needed.

**EDIT: This worked**

The Style

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The Window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SolidColorBrush backgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    public SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor
    {
        get { return backgroundColor; }
        set
        {
            if (backgroundColor == value)
                return;

            backgroundColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(backgroundColor));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Make sure to set the DataContext to this!
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the color through the property
        if (BackgroundColor.Color == Colors.Black)
            BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        else
            BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
}
```

This binds to the View, where you might want to abstract this to a ViewModel and bind to that. Also, if you do move this color logic to a ViewModel you also may want to change the `SolidColorBrush` in the BackgroundColor property to just a Color or some other UI-Independent type, but it is up to you. Check out [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ivo_manolov/2012/03/17/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-applications-general-introduction/) and other WPF MVVM related articles for more info on MVVM and Binding to ViewModels

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this approach. If I add <TabPanel></TabPanel> into the xmal, there will be an additional tab item added to the tab control. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I did not know if you had static tab panels or not. Sorry about that. Stick to the style approach to make it work effectively without having a static tab panel. I will try to update my answer when I am off mobile.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to WPF and C#, as a result, the style approach also confuses me. If you have time to update your answer, I will really appreciate that. :)

Comment: Make sure you implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your binding source as well!

Comment: It worked like a champ! Thank you so much! BTW, what do you mean by (implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your binding source)? I didn't remember I had done such a thing, but it still worked. :D (Marked as the answer)

Comment: Look at the `MainWindow` class. See how it implements INotifyPropertyChanged? That is required for bindings in WPF to work. Read up on it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx). I recommend you spend some time reading up on MVVM as well, it will be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will definitely read the articles that you recommended. :)